# Yes, another CORS query. I feel like I have done everything listed but still no beans

Tags: reactjs, axios, aws-api-gateway

I hope you are OK given the current World we all live in. Please can you help with an AWS API Gateway CORS issue. Here is what I have done and yet I still get a

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://XXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/live/record?id=8. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Response. I am passing an AWS API request through to a Lambda function shown below.

```
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": JSON.stringify({
      record: values[0],
      prev: values[1],
      next: values[2]
    }),
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,GET",
      "Access-Contol-Allow-Credentials": true
    }

  }
```

Within the proxy response I have the following headers within the OPTIONS method
[image]
And my Axios request within my create-react-app is thus...

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://XXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/live/record?id=${id}`,{
      crossdomain: true
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      setRecord(response.data.record)
      setNext(response.data.next)
      setPrev(response.data.prev)
      setMarker([response.data.record.y, response.data.record.x])
    })
  },[id])
```

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

OK - solved. Not sure which of the moving parts was needed. Originally I had https but changed it to http as a part of the testing. Changed it back, and it works. I would be interested to know if something is *not* needed here.